# Best and efficient way to parse both XML and HTML in C

Tags: html, c, xml, parsing

folks!
I'm looking for the best and efficient way to parse server responds that content both HTML and XML stuff. The respond come from servers I need to poll each 5 minutes (it's about half a thousand of them in list currently, but it will double very soon). Respond stored in buffer as plane text (got from socket). So, I need to parse HTML part and in case of success (mandatory things found) I should then try to parse XML part and get statistics information to store in DB. The responses are like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Length: 682
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 09 Mar 2014 15:44:52 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 09 Mar 2014 15:44:52 GMT
Server: DrWebAV-DeskServer/REL-610-AV-6.02.0.201311040 Linux/x86_64 Lua/5.1.4 OpenSSL/1.0.0e

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><avdesk-xml-api API='2.1.0' API_BUILD='20130709' branch='REL-610-AV' oper='get-server-info' rc='true' timestamp='20140309154452987' version='6.02.0.201311040'><server><id>00c1d140-d21d-b211-a828-b62919c4250d</id><platform>Linux 2.6.39-gentoo-r3 x86_64 (4 SMP Mon Oct 24 11:04:40 YEKT 2011)</platform><version>6.02.0.201311040</version><statistics from='20140301000000000' till='20140309235959999'><noviruses/><stations total='101'><online>5</online><deinstalled>21</deinstalled><blocked>0</blocked><expired>81</expired><offline>96</offline><activated>74</activated><unactivated>27</unactivated></stations></statistics></server></avdesk-xml-api>
```

And could be smth. like this

```
HTTP/1.0 401 Authorization Required
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: close
Content-Length: 421
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 09 Mar 2014 15:44:22 GMT
Expires: Date: Sat, 27 Nov 2004 10:18:15 GMT
Last-Modified: Date: Sat, 27 Nov 2004 10:18:15 GMT
Pragma: no-cahe
Server: DrWebAV-DeskServer/REL-610-AV-6.02.0.201311040 Linux/x86_64 Lua/5.1.4 OpenSSL/1.0.1
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Dr.Web XML API area"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"><HTML><TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE><BODY><STRONG>Unauthorized</STRONG><P>The error "401 Unauthorized" occured while processing request you had sent.<P><BR><BR><I>Access denied or your browser does not support HTTP authentication!</I><BR><P><BR><BR><HR><P>Dr.Web &reg; AV-Desk Server REL-610-AV 6.02.0.201311040 Linux/x86_64 Lua/5.1.4 OpenSSL/1.0.1</BODY></HTML>
```

Concerning HTML part I'm basically interested in HTTP/1.0 STRING and Server: STRING stuff, and then need per-tag XML parsing, if authorization succeeded.
I have found, that libxml2 is suitable for parsing both HTML/XML stuff, but unable to find any real examples how to use it, just some major interface description. So, help needed.

Comment: Websearch for "libxml2 html" quickly finds articles/manuals for libxml2. What do you need that those aren't giving you?

Comment: Parsing HTML responses in C is like cutting a tree in a forest with a herring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code examples for `libxml2` are [here](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html)

The mailing list is friendly, and the code is mature and good quality.

However, nothing in your example suggests you need to parse HTML. You need to parse (I think) HTTP to process the headers (and detect the 401 error from the HTTP response), then parse the XML content. Parsing HTTP headers to the level you require it is trivial (just `strtok` the response separating on line breaks and the first line has the answer you need). The body of the response starts after a double line break (I think your second example has a paste error). This reduces your task to simply processing HTTP headers and XML (no HTML parsing).

Comment: Well.. yes, it's HTTP rather then HTML. And I'm interested primarily in what's after HTTP/1.0 stuff to be able to make a decision if I should continue parsing the XML part or throw an error. I don't need to use any external library, just because I can analyze headers using just string.h stuff. But I still have no idea how to parse that type of XML. I did a try using xmlReadMemory, xmlDocGetRootElement and xmlNodeGetContent, but with a little luck because of format.